# Non GPL XMPP client library

Tags: c++, c, windows, xmpp

Does any one know of a good xmpp client library that isn't under GPL license?

Preferred written in c or c++

Edit: Also compiles on windows

Comment: Trying looking on Freshmeat, you can refine by license http://freshmeat.net/search?q=xmpp&submit=Search

Answer (score 4):

[libjingle](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) - Its under New BSD License.

(edit)Can be compile on windows as well as on linux

Comment: Yes. version 0.50 is recently released by google. It supports jingle, mingle (google's jingle) and hybrid(jingle and mingle both). Check out its example. It has support for chat, audio and video

Comment: Ended up being to complicated to compile. Rolled my own basic chat lib in around 100 lines of code.

Comment: I compiled it once. Its easy 2-3 hour job

Answer (score 2):

[qxmpp](http://code.google.com/p/qxmpp/) It is LGPL.
It is based on Qt, so can be compiled on windows too.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of information I will post this here. I hope your implementation went well.

[txmpp](https://github.com/silas/txmpp) is released under New BSD License.